# How to use LIKE a check only 6 mark?

Tags: mysql

I have a database table products, which contains a column called store_id, and in it:

```
11001100
11111111
11000000
11111011
```

6 For example, if the character is equal to 1 is in the store is the product.

How to use LIKE a check only 6 mark?

Comment: Do you mean that `store_id` is a varchar datatype?

Comment: What do you mean by _check only 6 mark_? Do you mean the 6th character in the `store_id`?

Comment: So no one else thinks this unclear?

Comment: I believe an underscore is the matches 1 character, so it might be `'_____1%'` but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: If you want to check a particular character, use `SUBSTR()`, not `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) function to get a particular part of a string. You can specify the starting index, as well as the length of characters to retrieve. That being said, if you want to find the sixth character in the string, try this:

```
SUBSTRING(store_id, 6, 1)
```

Inside your query, it would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE SUBSTRING(store_id, 6, 1) = '1';
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e0c9/4) example.

---

If you *must* use the `LIKE` operator as your title and question suggest, you need to know that an underscore matches a single character in MySQL. Knowing that, you can look for strings that have 5 starting characters, a 1, and who cares after that. The percent symbol is used to check for 0 or more characters:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE store_id LIKE '_____1%';
```

Comment: @Kwiatkowski which solution did you use, if you don't mind me asking? The substring or like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) to extract a character from the string.

To select all products in store 6, use:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p
WHERE SUBSTRING(p.Store_Id, 6, 1) = '1'
```

Or the slightly more verbal syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p
WHERE SUBSTRING(p.Store_Id FROM 6 FOR 1) = '1'
```

That said, this is not very efficient. A better approach would be to make a separate table to link a product to a store, for instance a table `StoreProduct` that has a Product_Id and a (real) Store_Id. Then, you can write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p
INNER JOIN StoreProduct sp ON sp.Product_Id = p.ProductId
WHERE sp.Store_Id = 6 /* The actual id of the store */
```

This query looks more complex, but with proper indexes it is more efficient.

Comment: 'There are 10 kinds of people...'

Comment: '.. Those who know binary, those who don't, and those who weren't expecting this joke to be in base 3.'  @Strawberry